# Google API Geocoding OVER_QUERY_LIMIT , 5 addresses per second?

Tags: javascript, google-api, geocoding

First of all, I didn't reach the maximum daily limit of 2,500 addresses.

I have 25 addresses, and I already set the sleep time in JavaScript between each address to 5 seconds. I always get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error after 18 or 19 addresses are geocoded. The rest 7 or 6 address always not get geocoded.

Google API Geocoding as limit of 5 addresses per second, or they have increased?

Thanks.

Code

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, addresses ) {

    var arrayLength = addresses.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var address = String(addresses[i]);
   // alert(address)
    sleep(5000) 
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) 
    {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var result = results[0].geometry.location;
                var name = results[0].formatted_address;
                writeFile(geocode_file_path, name + ',' + result.toString());
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
var start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
        break;
        }
}   
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like? If you fire 25 at once and then sleep for 5 seconds, it's not going to help.

Comment: function geocodeAddress(geocoder, addresses ) {
        var arrayLength = addresses.length;
 
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            var address = String(addresses[i]);
     sleep(5000) 
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) 
        {

Comment: The addresses go through a loop as copied above. When pass over each address, I set sleep(5000) , which is 5 seconds. The sleep function works.

Comment: `sleep()`? How is that implemented?

Comment: I copied the code for the addresses loop through function, and sleep function above

Comment: ahhh. That sleep function is 'not good'. You are no doubt blasting through the loop before your time is up. Use `setTimeout()` or switch to promises. I recommend BluebirdJS

Comment: why the sleep function doesn't work? I timed it, it works.

Comment: Your `geocoder.gecode` function is asynchronous. This may cause requests to eventually stack despite the `sleep`

Comment: how to solve the problem that geocoder.gecode function is asynchronous? Using setTimeout() still will not solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex problem. Async is very tricky to get your head around.

Having said that, here's a solution that would work. I would prefer a Promise based solution but Promises are another issue that takes time to understand.

```
function geocodeAddresses(geocoder, addresses, callback){

    var result = [];

    // this internal function does the hard work
    function geocode(address) {
        // get timestamp so we can use it to throttle later
        var lastCall = Date.now();
        // call google function asynchronously
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
            // process the return data here
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                result.push({
                    location: results[0].geometry.location,
                    address: results[0].formatted_address
                });
            } else {
                result.push({ error: status });
            }

            // check to see if there are any more addresses to geocode
            if (addresses.length) {
                // calculate when next call can be made. 200ms is 5 req / second
                var throttleTime = 200 - (lastCall - Date.now());
                setTimeout(function(){      // create timeout to run in 'throttletime` ms
                    // call this function with next address
                    geocode(addresses.shift());
                }, throttleTime);

            } else {        // all done return result
                callback(result);
            }

        });
    }

    // start the process - geocode will call itself for any remaining addresses
    geocode(addresses.shift());
}
```

Since this function is asynchronous, you have to use it asynchronously ... hence the callback. So you use it as follows:

```
geocodeAddresses(geocoder, addresses, function(result){
    // do what you need with the result here
    console.log(result);
});
```

This is about as simple as I can make it. I've created a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/hebepuyihu/edit?js,console) that mocks out the geocoder call and shows real results. Change the throttleTime to bigger numbers to see it slow down.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Wainage! But, it doesn't work.  I tried repeatedly just run without time delay function, I found Google API let me geocode 15 addresses, after that it shows "query over limit". If using Sleep function, set time between 1000 ms to 100000 ms, Google API sometimes geocodes 23 out of 24 locations, sometimes still only geocode 15 addresses. I think I might get multiple keys to geocode more than 15 locations.